# Programa sendo executado inteiro mesmo depois de uma condição ser colocada (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou aprendendo python e oque acontece é o seguinte:

Tenho alguns if's no programa mas mesmo depois de uma das condições ser suprida o programa continua sendo executado inteiro, ocasionando em um erro

```
import os



acao = input("Olá, qual ação gostaria de realizar?\n"
             "1 - Link do perfil\n"
             "2 - Encontrar perfil\n"
             "Resposta: ")



if acao == "Link":
    pesq2 = input('Selecione a rede social que deseja usar:\n'
                  '1 - Instagram\n'
                  '2 - Facebook\n'
                  '3 - Twitter\n'
                  '4 - Tiktok \n'
                  'Resposta: ')


if pesq2 == "Instagram":
    pesq3 = input('Digite o perfil que deseja pesquisar: ')
    inst = "instagram.com/" + pesq3
    os.system("start chrome " + inst)




if pesq2 == "Facebook":
    pesq3 = input('Digite o perfil que deseja pesquisar: ')
    fc = "facebook.com/" + pesq3
    os.system("start chrome " + fc)





elif pesq2 == "Twitter":
    pesq3 = input('Digite o perfil que deseja pesquisar: ')

    tw = "twitter.com/" + pesq3
    os.system("start chrome " + tw)




elif acao == "Encontrar":
    bsc = input("Selecione a rede social: "
                "1 - Perfil Facebook\n"
                "2 - Perfil Tiktok\n"
                "3 - Perfil Twitter\n")


if bsc == "Facebook":
    pfac = input("Digite o perfil que deseja pesquisar: ")
    fac1 = "https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=" + pfac
    os.system("start chrome " + fac1)

    if bsc == "Tiktok":
        ptk = input("Digite o perfil desejado: ")
        ptk1 = "https://www.tiktok.com/search?q=" + ptk
        os.system("start chrome " + ptk1 + "&lang=pt-BR")
```

Oque acontece, é que ao digitar "Encontrar" o programa pula para  `if pesq2 == "Instagram"` e acaba dando erro pois pesq2 não foi declarado.

Isso foi desorganização da minha parte (e inexperiencia) ? como posso resolver?

Comment: A indentacao no python tem função lógica, organize a indentacao que você entenderá o problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa usar seus condicionais aninhados. Isso significa que um `if` tem que estar dentro do outro. Você faz isso usando a indentação:

```
acao = input("Olá, qual ação gostaria de realizar?\n"
             "1 - Link do perfil\n"
             "2 - Encontrar perfil\n"
             "Resposta: ")

if acao == "Link":
    pesq2 = input('Selecione a rede social que deseja usar:\n'
                  '1 - Instagram\n'
                  '2 - Facebook\n'
                  '3 - Twitter\n'
                  '4 - Tiktok \n'
                  'Resposta: ')

    if pesq2 == "Instagram":
        pesq3 = input('Digite o perfil que deseja pesquisar: ')
        inst = "instagram.com/" + pesq3
        os.system("start chrome " + inst)

    elif pesq2 == "Facebook":
        pesq3 = input('Digite o perfil que deseja pesquisar: ')
        fc = "facebook.com/" + pesq3
        os.system("start chrome " + fc)

    elif pesq2 == "Twitter":
        pesq3 = input('Digite o perfil que deseja pesquisar: ')

        tw = "twitter.com/" + pesq3
        os.system("start chrome " + tw)

elif acao == "Encontrar":
    bsc = input("Selecione a rede social: "
                "1 - Perfil Facebook\n"
                "2 - Perfil Tiktok\n"
                "3 - Perfil Twitter\n")
```

você percebe que todos os condicionais que dizem respeito a `pesq2` estão alinhados e dentro do primeiro `if`? Além disso tome muito cuidado com o uso do `if/elif` em alguns lugares você usou `if` quando deveria ser `elif`